# Need two WCF Services on Azure

Tags: azure, wcf

I have on Azure a running Azure Cloud Service. 
This service is used by my program. I can not change this service anymore, because otherwise I would have to update 200 ~ users. I now wanted to create a new WCF service that runs alongside the old service. In the new program version I wanted to use this WCF2 service. But I can not publish the WCF2 in Azure, he always wants to override the old WCF.
How do I get both WCF service running at Azure at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can host multiple applications within the same cloud service site. In your ServiceDefinition.csfg update the `<site>`element to add one or more `VirtualApplication` elements with “physicalDirectory” property for each pointing to a relative directory on your build machine which contains the appropriate built WCF project.

Publishing will be slightly more complicated because now publishing the cloud service will not auto-build the related projects. You will have to build solution the right-click-> publish each WCF1 and WCF2 to separate folders. “physicalDirectory” will point to those folders.

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="MyWCFServices" physicalDirectory="..\..\Empty">
    <VirtualApplication name="Wcf1Service" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\..\Publish\Wcf1Service" />
    <VirtualApplication name="Wcf2Service" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\..\Publish\Wcf2Service" />
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="MyWCFServicesEndpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

At that point you can publish the cloud service and two virtual apps will be created on the same instance. Of course this requires that you have two separate projects (one for each wcf version).

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you show me a sample how does it works? Here my current ServiceDefinition.csdef
WCF2

<ServiceDefinition name="Mobiler_Lieferschein_AzureCloudServiceV4" 
  <WebRole name="WCFServiceWebRoleV2" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="EndpointV1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
   
      <InputEndpoint name="EndpointV1" protocol="http" port="86" />

Comment: I added a sample XML. Just make sure that all three physicalDirectory locations exist on disk when publishing. The "Empty" directory should have a single empty file (i have a .txt in there). On the VM it will create three subfolders in the e:\sitesroot called 0, 1, 2. Folder 0 will have contents of the \Empty directory and the other two will have contents of the WCF services.